# Why does sed's regex grouping differ from normal regex?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grouping

I'm struggling to understand why is sed messing up a simple regular expression.

I've got the following input inside a file called `test`:

```
dbname=example user=example password=1234
```

And the following regular expression:

```
(dbname=)[^\s]+
```

And I want to replace `dbname=example` with, say, `dbname=dovecot`, but without knowing the value of `dbname` beforehand. To do so, I understand I should do:

```sh
sed -E "s;(dbname=)[^\\s]+;\1dovecot;g test"
```

However, I get `dbname=dovecotser=example password=1234` instead of `dbname=dovecot user=example password=1234`.

So, to try and understand sed's logic I simplified the input to:

```
dbname=example user=example
```

And I modified my regex so I could see what was going on with the groups. The following regular expression should match `dbname=` as `\1`, `example` as `\2`,   as `\3` and `user=example` as `\4`:

```
(dbname=)([^\s]+)([\s]+)([^\s]+)
```

And it does, at least when using common sense and [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), for instance.

Therefore, why is sed returning `dbname=` as `\1`, which is correct, but `example u` as `\2`, `s` as `\3` and `er=example` as `\4` when running the following?

```
$ sed -E "s;(dbname=)([^\\s]+)([\\s]+)([^\\s]+);\1;g" test
dbname=
$ sed -E "s;(dbname=)([^\\s]+)([\\s]+)([^\\s]+);\2;g" test
example u
$ sed -E "s;(dbname=)([^\\s]+)([\\s]+)([^\\s]+);\3;g" test
s
$ sed -E "s;(dbname=)([^\\s]+)([\\s]+)([^\\s]+);\4;g" test
er=example
```

Did I do anything wrong? Is sed using a different approach to regular expressions I don't know of?

Many thanks.

*Note: I'm using `;` as sed's delimiter for clarity.*

Comment: You need `sed -E "s;(dbname=)\S+;\1dovecot;g"`, or `sed -E "s;(dbname=)[^[:space:]]+;\1dovecot;g"`

Comment: Wow that was quick, thank you, it does work, but is there a reason why negation is not working (`[^\\s]`)?

Comment: Because regex escape sequences are not treated as such inside bracket expressions (in POSIX regexps).

Comment: I understand, thank you very much, I wasn't aware of that and I was beginning to go mental. I see there is a similar question I haven't found before I posted this, should I delete mine then?

Comment: You can keep it, it is well asked.

Comment: @Jose `\s` is shorthand for the bracket expression which contains a character class `[[:space:]]`, not for just the character class `[:space:]`. Trying to use `\s` inside a bracket expression `[\s]` is like trying to use `[[[:space:]]]`.

Comment: Oh, and the opposite of `\s` is `\S`, you don't need to try to write `[^\s]` anyway. Also - web sites like regex101 are only good for validating that a regexp behaves a specific way **on that web site**, not for how it'll behave in any given command line tool - you have to learn which regexp variant the tool uses (BRE, ERE, or PCRE), how delimiters and/or command line options impact it, whether or not backreferences are enabled in the replacement text and/or the regexp, etc.

Comment: I see, it makes sense, thanks!